# How to configure Shibboleth2 to send SAML response via header to app

Tags: http, header, single-sign-on, identity, shibboleth

I have an application, in SSO mode, making use of Shibboleth 2 as identity provider.
I am trying to configure Shibboleth 2 (via `shibboleth-config.yaml`) to pass the whole SAML response in a header format, among other user data upon making a login request.

To configure a response header, I used some XML config like the following:

```
<Attribute name="http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" id="...">
        <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="StringAttributeDecoder" caseSensitive="false"/>
    </Attribute>
```

Is it possible to pass a whole SAML response in the header through a similar config? And if so, how can I configure that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to pass a whole SAML response in the header

No, this is not possible, because there is no SAML proctocol binding defined to achieve this. Please have a look at http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf